# Fedora 30 on Macbook Pro - cannot remap caps lock

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm running Fedora 30 (gnome desktop) on a 2015 Macbook Pro, and am trying to remap caps lock to ctrl when held down and escape when pressed. To do this, I ran:

```
setxkbmap -option 'ctrl:nocaps' && xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect on caps lock (of the built-in mac keyboard).

**UPDATE**

After further investigation, this seems to be related to gnome. In i3, the `setxkbmap` runs correctly, and the `xcape` line works properly if I change it to instead be `xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'`, presumably because the setxkbmap rerouted caps to ctrl already before xcape runs. Question still stands for how to get this working in gnome though.